# IIS 7 and FastCGI Problem

Tags: php, iis-7, fastcgi

Today I was configuring IIS 7 with FastFGI in Windows 7. I followed all the steps but I get the following error:

> C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI
>   process exited unexpectedly
>
> - IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the
>     processing of the request. The root
>     cause of this error depends on which
>     module handles the request and what
>     was happening in the worker process
>     when this error occurred.
> - IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or
>     application. This can occur if the
>     NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
> - IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or
>     application.
> - The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
> - The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility
>     Feature is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually get this error?  This seems like multiple "this could be the case" errors, so I'm not sure exactly which one you're running into.

A lot of the bullet points, however, seem to be related to permissons, so I would start there.

Can you access the pages you're trying to render?  In other words can you throw an HTML file in the same directory and get to the page?  If not, you have to muddle around with windows permissions.  Either set the website to use your permissions, or modify the IIS_IUSR (i think that's what it's called) account.

The only thing that throws me off is that it's exiting unexpectedly, which I suppose could also be permissions, but I don't know why it would crash.  Possibly PHP itself doesn't have access to files you're trying to get to?  I can't tell from this error message.

Again, this looks like a "could be A, could be B" error message, but PHP will cerainly crash if you're trying to run it in "managed mode" -- a.k.a. within the .NET runtime, as PHP is not compiled with .NET.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

When I installed it on IIS 6, I had to put my php.ini file in the Windows folder:
http://www.howtoadvice.com/PHPIIS

Answer (score 0):

Despite of how old the question is I found the same issue over and over in different sites.
The answer is mostly always, missing files. For some reason the installation in Windows doesn't always work well, even when I used Web Platform Installer it is necessary to check the lo